# SSIS: can I write formulas to a destination spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, ssis

I am using SSIS to write data from a SQL source to an Excel destination. Plugging in hardcoded values is fine. However, I've been requested to put in SUM() formulas in the last column. They want the actual formula, not the summed value, which I could do on the SSIS side.

I wrote a formula that worked and added it as an additional column in my data transform:

```
"=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,ROW()-1,3,1,9))"
```

HOWEVER, when I open my target spreadsheet, this formula is just plugged in as text. It will not evaluate unless I expressly edit the cell (just click in and out). F9, Shift-F9, etc do not work.

I'm pretty sure there's no way to overcome this, but I thought I'd check. I am open to other solutions. I cannot pre-fill the formulas, since the amount of data I'm adding is variable.

I should also mention that I do not want to use any solution that requires manipulating Excel via the Interop library. The entire point of this exercise is to stop using Excel on the server machine, so I can only install the relevant driver, not Excel itself.

Comment: remove the double quotations and change the Cells Number Format to `General`

Comment: If you're not willing to use interop, then you're probably right, there's no way to do this.